# Besides Indo-Pacific and Australian languages does anywhere "firewood" semantically develop to "fire"?

Tags: etymology, semantics, proto-indo-european

It is known that in Australian languages the word for "tree" developed into "firewood" and then to "fire". I wonder if this development typical?

Particularly, could PIE **h₁n̥gʷnís* "fire" be related to **h₁n̥gʷḗn* "swelling, branch", **h₁óngʷl* "charcoal"?

What about Uralic development?

Comment: Can  you provide research to corroborate that?

Comment: How is this "known"? The only detailed examination of this question that I know of is the one by [Schapper, San Roque and Hendery](https://researchdirect.westernsydney.edu.au/islandora/object/uws%3A37704), in which they look at this issue for languages of Sahul. While they weren't focused on studying the pathways of development for these colexifications, they didn't find a single pathway in evidence and give an example of a language that extended 'firewood/fire' to 'tree', and another that did the opposite.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut well, I was talking about the root which was sounding like dyung(u)-. I do not remember the source but it  stated that it  is common knowledge that this root initially meant "tree". It seems, Shapper also confirms this idea. It is this root that is interesting for me because it is similar to the PIE one. Also, in proto-FU we have *täŋkɜ (firewood), *äŋɜ- (fire), **taŋɜ- (swelling) (here ɜ is unknown vowel) as well as Chukchi *jǝ́n (firewood), Proto-Yupik *ǝknǝ-, Aleut *qigna-x́, Burushaski hun, etc. These branches show similar semantincs of the root ~dyung(u)-.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut It seems, this root co-existed with the initial root for fire, *péh₂wr̥ (PIE), *päjwä (PFU), *pʰu (Burush)

Comment: There, I did it for you https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46455/semantic-drift-between-wood-fire-wood-and-fire so I can feel a little needed

Comment: Yes Schapper et al mention the root ''dyung(u)'' in the Northern Daly language family as co-lexifying 'tree', 'fire' and 'firewood', but they don't claim any direction of development. I'm very curious to know your source for it initially meaning 'tree'. BTW Northern Daly is only one (small) language family of >12 in Australia so cannot support a claim re Australian languages generally.