# Semantic drift between wood, fire-wood and fire

Tags: etymology, semantics, australian-languages

Following the discussion about [question related](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46452/besides-indo-pacific-and-australian-languages-does-anywhere-firewood-semantica?noredirect=1#comment107986_46452), because comments aren't intended for extended discussion: Can you provide research to corroborate that *It is known that in Australian languages the word for "tree" developed into "firewood" and then to "fire"* (@Anixx)?

Two comments provide preliminary answers:

> [...] The only detailed examination of this question that I know of is the one by [Schapper, San Roque and Hendery](https://researchdirect.westernsydney.edu.au/islandora/object/uws%3A37704) in which they look at this issue for languages of Sahul. While they weren't focused on studying the pathways of development for these colexifications, they didn't find a single pathway in evidence and give an example of a language that extended 'firewood/fire' to 'tree', and another that did the opposite. – *Gaston Ümlaut 16 hours ago*

> @GastonÜmlaut well, I was talking about the root which was sounding like *dyung(u)-*. I do not remember the source but it stated that it is common knowledge that this root initially meant "tree". It seems, Shapper also confirms this idea. [...] – *Anixx 2 hours ago*

For the sake of the argument, the question is limited to Australian languages.